# Bundler found in root but not in app dir?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler

`bundler -v` when run in root directory returns; `Bundler version 1.13.6`

When i move to a newly pulled down app directory `bundler -v` returns; `command not found`.

Can you help me understand why bundler is found in one dir and not the other? `Ruby -v` returns 2.2.2 in both locations.

Comment: are you using the same gemset? Check with `rvm gemset list` in both places.

Comment: Within the newly pulled down app directory: `rvm gemset list` returns 

`gemsets for ruby-2.2.2 (found in /Users/jbkimac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2)
=> (default)
   global`

Within root directory `rvm gemset list` returns 

`gemsets for ruby-2.3.0 (found in /Users/jbkimac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0)
=> (default)
   global`

Comment: You sure ruby -v is the same?

Comment: My profuse apologies, Ruby -v is 2.2.2 in the app dir and 2.3.0 in root. So does that mean I have to install bundler again in the app directory and ruby 2.2.2 environment?

Comment: What it probobly means is the gemfile in the gem you pulled down has a ruby version different from your default version. Yes, install bundler in that directory and it will work.

Comment: Thanks Secretmaster, all sorted.